# tensorflow object detection Fine-tuning a model from an existing checkpoint

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to train a model from an existing checkpoint following the these
[instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md).

I have [configured](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md#configuring-the-trainer) the Object Detection Training Pipeline using the [faster_rcnn_resnet101_voc07.config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_voc07.config) configuration.

In checkpoint section I have set the directory where are located the checkpoint files of the pretrained model [faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.tar.gz](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017.tar.gz)

Acording the to this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2173) the **fine_tune_checkpoint** can be a path to a directory containing the three files:  (.data-00000-of-00001, .index, .meta).

So I set the path to the directory "*/home/docs/car_dataset/models/model/train*"

```
gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/docs/car_dataset/models/model/train"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 800000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
```

However when I execute the script for training:

```
python object_detection/train.py     --logtostderr\
--pipeline_config_path=/home/docs/car_dataset/models/model/faster_rcnn_resnet101_voc07.config\
--train_dir=/home/docs/car_dataset/models/model/train\
--num_gpus=2
```

I got the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file /home/docs/car_dataset/models/model/train: Failed precondition: /home/docs/car_dataset/models/model/train: perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

I have also tried setting the path to every file in the directory

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/docs/car_dataset/models/model/train/model.ckpt.meta"
```

but I get the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file /home/docs/car_dataset/models/model/train/model.ckpt.meta: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

What is the correct way to define a pre trained model in the pipeline configuration having the three files: (.data-00000-of-00001, .index, .meta).

**Tensorflow version:** 1.2.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have to do is to specify the whole path without the ".meta", ".index" and ".data-00000-of-00001" extensions.  In your case, this looks to be:
"/home/docs/car_dataset/models/model/train/model.ckpt" (which you'll notice is more specific than the directory).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the path the following way works for me,
~/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_640x640/checkpoint/ckpt-0

ckpt-0 is the name of the index file without the .index extension